# Can't load "academic.microsoft.com" site on Webview

Tags: java, android, browser, webview

I wan't to load https://academic.microsoft.com site on webview, but blank page appears instead, here is my code

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("https://academic.microsoft.com");
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Make sure the webview width/height is not set to `"wrap_content"`. Instead use `"match_parent"`

2.Try using `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Comment: I solved it by adding this three lines webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); Thanks a lot